# invalid double conversion error on edittext

Tags: java, android

I'm new to programming and I having trouble figuring out why the below code would cause the error.  What is causing the v1 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ?

```
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int                  position  , long id){

           double answer;

           TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);

           EditText value;

            value = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

            if(position == 0){

            v1 = Double.parseDouble(value.getText().toString());

                mTextView.setText(Double.toString(answer));
            }
```

Comment: what is the value of `value.getText().toString()` ?

Comment: initally there is nothing typed in it. But I want to be able to have the program load without crashing to input something in the editText then parse that to a double

Comment: so check to make sure that `value.getText().` is not null or empty

Comment: how would I do that? I believe that even when I tried that it still errored out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that the value that you are trying to parse is not null

```
String dv = null;
if (value.getText() != null) {
    dv = value.getText().toString ();
}
if(position == 0 && dv != null){

        v1 = Double.parseDouble(dv);
        mTextView.setText(Double.toString(answer));
}
```

Comment: you also need to catch the exception if the user is inputting random stuff (on most android keyboards, even numeric input types will let you input both `.` and `,` any number of times)

Comment: even when I check to see if its null the app wont even start up, it still says Unfortnately myapp has stopped working and gives  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""